# Можно ли в Docker сделать одну операционную систему на два образа, таких как "Интерпрeтатор серверного языка" и "база данных"?

Tags: docker

Допустим, мне требуетмя стэк из **NodeJS** и базы данных **PostgreSQL**.
Файл **docker-compse.yml** в данном случае будет выглядеть как-то так:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  node:
    container_name: node_express
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    tty:  true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/posrgresql/data
      - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Насколько мне известно, образы **node** и **posgres** независимы, иначе говоря, каждый находится внутри собственной изолированной операционной системы (скорее всего семейста Linux). Если это так, то отдельная OS для NodeJS и Posgres - это слишком большой расход дисковой памяти, а в условиях VPS за неё платить каждый месяц (и немало, ибо как правило это SSD). Даже образ с пустым Node.JS-приложением образ уже весит порядка 1гБ, а если ещё и база данных со своей ОС, то под один только "Hello, world" из Node.js и Posgres придётся арендовать гигабайта 2.

Я прекрасно понимаю, что с точки зрения хорошей инстраструктуры лучше отдельные образы для NodeJS и Postgres (более того, по мере развития приложения у базы данных наверняка появится дублирование для повышения безопасности), но для стадии разработки, альфа- и бета- тестирования нужно более экономное решение.

Если ли способ в Docker как-нибудь обобщить OS для NodeJS и Posgre (впрочем, на их месте может быть любой язык, поддерживающий серверное программирование и любая база данных)?

Comment: Выбирайте нужные вам образы. посмотрите списки доступных https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres  После названия основной программы образа и версии через тире обычно указана используемая ОС. лучше всего брать alpine, она очень компактная. Например берете: `postgres:14-alpine` и `node:18-alpine`. Дополнительно можно заглянуть в Dockerfile образа и убедится что версия alpine используется одна и та же

Comment: P.S. сам образ alpine 5.5Mb, если что

Comment: @Mike, благодарю Вас за рекомендацию! Не могли бы подсказать, чем объясняется маленький размер alpine-версий? Я очень рад, что они такие миниатюрные, но обязан знать, почему. Не отсутствует ли в них какая-нибудь важная функциональность, доступная в базовых версиях? А что насчёт ОС, внутри которой существуют базы данных и интерпретторы alpine-версий?

Comment: alpine дистрибутив для встраиваемых систем вроде прошивок роутеров и т.п.  Там две важные части linux сильно порезаны. Вместо libc используется musl, не знаю что из нее выброшено, думаю поддержка языков и еще что то не важное. с точки зрения остальных программ набор функций ОС которые она дает достаточен. И стандартный набор утилит командной строки (вроде cp, mv, ps, и шелл sh) вместо отдельных программ представлены одним единственным файлом busybox в них сильно меньше всяких редко используемых ключей. Ну и документация вроде man выброшена

Comment: Вопрос на счет ОС не понял, alpine и есть ОС. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux